# Copy colored text from Windows command line and Linux shell

Tags: shell, command-line, colors

Is there a way to retain color when copying text from a command line in Windows and Linux?

Comment: hi, all-who-closed-or-down-weighted:

My question lies in following two categories: 
1) software tools commonly used by programmers
2) practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
-----

Could any of you point out what rule am I violating? In case you misunderstood my issue: I am referring to the color which command line tools add to output (for example, grep). However that color is lost while copying text into Microsoft Word or any other application. It is a valid issue which many programmers face. What do you do in this scenario?

Comment: Here's a similar question in superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/77781/how-to-copy-text-from-the-cmd-console-and-keep-the-formatting-with-color

Answer (score 1):

I found no mechanism to instruct my terminal of choice, `urxvt`, to include the color formatting codes when selecting text. If you don't mind taking an extra step, you can use the `script(1)` program to record a `typescript` file of all input and output on the terminal, and this file will retain the color escape sequences -- as well as all passwords, backspaces, etc., that you might have typed.